# Gson - Deserialize objects by specifying class, not parametrization

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

I have the following classes:

```
public class Top {
   private String key;
...
}

public class A extends Top {
   private String aValue;
...
}

public class Complex {
   private String field;
   private List<Top> objects;
}
```

I want to deserialize a json String into a "Complex" class and specify that "objects" elements are of type "A".

I have tried 2 methods:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .registerTypeAdapter(A.class, new InstanceCreator<A>() {

            @Override
            public A createInstance(Type arg0) {
                return new A();
            }
        })  //method 1
        .registerTypeHierarchyAdapter(A.class, new My_A_Adapter()) //method 2
        .create();

Complex complexObject = gson.fromJson(json, Complex.class); 
A = (A) complexObject.getObjects().get(0);  // This throws ClassCastException
```

But the type of complexObject.getObjects().get(0) is "Top" so i cannot cast it to "A".

I do not want to parameterize the Complex class, (for ex. Complex) because i want to add more collections of generic objects in time...

What solution do I have ?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12117789/1856960.  `RuntimeTypeAdapterFactory` might be what you need, but I don't think it comes with GSON, so you will have to add the source.