# Classname as a json field

Tags: java, json, jackson

#### Introduction

I need to serialize a java object (`Fahrweg`) that contains nested objects (all implement the interface `FahrwegEreignis`) to json.
My code to do this is as follows:

```
Fahrweg fahrweg = new Fahrweg();

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

mapper.addMixIn(FahrwegEreignis.class, FahrwegEreignisMixIn.class);

ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();

try {
  String json = ow.writeValueAsString(fahrweg);
  System.out.print(json);
} catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

By default, the type of the object is not contained in the resulting json (I assume because JS is dynamically typed).

I would like to add a field to every object about like so: `"type" : "classname"`.

I've read about the Jackson annotations, and I'm using mixin because I cannot modify the classes in question. My mixin interface (`FahrwegEreignisMixIn`) looks like this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public interface FahrwegEreignisMixIn {
    @JsonProperty("type")
    //TODO
}
```

#### Question

What do I need to put at `//TODO`?

My first instinct was `Class<?> getClass();` but that doesn't work.

#### Answer

The answer in the duplicate question worked for me. I had to change
my `FahrwegEreignisMixIn` to this:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonTypeInfo;

@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.CLASS, property = "type")
public interface FahrwegEreignisMixIn {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using [Google GSon](https://github.com/google/gson)? Works like a charm for me.

Your code would probably look like so:

```
FahrwegEreignis fahrweg = new Fahrweg();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(fahrweg);
```

Comment: I'll try this, thanks

Comment: "Works like a charm" yes, but it doesn't contain the class name either, right?

Comment: you can use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12117332/3504059) if I'm correct

Comment: @KoenVE Jackson also supports custom serializers, but due to the large amount of different classes I'd need to write it for I'd rather not do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following on the instance of the class that implements an interface:

```
FahrwegEreignisMixInImpl.getClass().getName()
```